# How to remove element from object while casting for Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

I would like to remove elements from an object to fit into another interface that has less properties. Using lodash.omit I can achieve this, but I'm looking for a native solution:

```
interface TeamAvatarHumans {
  earth: string;
  fire: string;
  air: string;
  water: string;
}

interface AvatarGroup {
  earth: string;
  fire: string;
  air: string;
  water: string;
  pets: string[]
}

const team: AvatarGroup = {
  earth: 'toph',
  fire: 'zuko',
  air: 'aang',
  water: 'katara',
  pets: ["momo", "aapa"]
};

const { pets, ...teamAvatar } = team;

// Native
console.log(teamAvatar)
// { earth: 'toph', fire: 'zuko', air: 'aang', water: 'katara' }
```

With this simple example the output will be good however the object `teamAvatar` cannot be type hinted TeamAvatarHumans.

With Lodash Omit I can do it:

```
const teamAvatar: TeamAvatarHumans = _.omit(team,"pets");
```

Is there a native Typescript way without lodash?

Comment: You could set a type using native `Omit`? `type WithoutPets = Omit<AvatarGroup, 'pets'>` and then set the `team` to be `team: WithoutPets = foo;`

Comment: I don't understand the question. `teamAvatar` in your code gets typed as equivalent to `TeamAvatarHumans`. What were you hoping for that you aren't getting?

Comment: @CertainPerformance "it is equivalent" but im not type hinting it. If I want to carry the object around or use any of its function afterward it won't have it.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I would like to not use any other function, native or lodash would mean it is the equivalent and not a shorter/optimized version of what I've found

Comment: It looks to be working fine on my end https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0CYJ.png

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes you will get the equivalent properties BUT it is not typed as `TeamAvatarHumans`